# Service account with org viewer role not able to perform any actions

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I have created a GCP service account with org viewer permissions (I assume therefore having read rights in all projects)

```
▶ gcloud organizations get-iam-policy 83838383838383 --flatten="bindings[].members" --format='table(bindings.role)' --filter="bindings.members:my-sa@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
ROLE
roles/resourcemanager.organizationViewer
```

I then activate this locally

```
▶ gcloud auth activate-service-account my-sa@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=keyfile.json
Activated service account credentials for: [my-sa@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
```

and then try to perform a `compute disk list` (on the same project the SA was created)

```
▶ gcloud compute disks list
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.disks.list) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Required 'compute.disks.list' permission for 'projects/my-project-id'
```

Why is that?

Comment: Add project viewer role to see the resources of the project

Comment: I did that and to my surprise it gave project viewer to __all__ projects under the same org

Comment: If you set project viewer at the org level, yes, you have project viewer role in all project of the org, by inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error messages states that the service account does not have the permission `compute.disks.list`.

What permissions does the role `roles/resourcemanager.organizationViewer` have?

```
gcloud iam roles describe roles/resourcemanager.organizationViewer --format=json
```

Notice that the role only has one permission `resourcemanager.organizations.get`

```
{
  "description": "Access only to view an Organization.",
  "etag": "AA==",
  "includedPermissions": [
    "resourcemanager.organizations.get"
  ],
  "name": "roles/resourcemanager.organizationViewer",
  "stage": "GA",
  "title": "Organization Viewer"
}
```

That permssions allows viewing the organization details, but not the resources of the organization.